# Unknown R package build error

Tags: r

I am trying to build my R package using RStudio with roxygen2. It runs through all the code fine (there is C++ code for which I am using `Rcpp` and there is nothing out of the ordinary during compilation either) but once it finishes going through the documentation

heavily truncated...

```
...
Writing NAMESPACE
```

it stops with the error:

> Exited with status -1073741819

I have tried using `devtools` directly where `devtools::document()` completes without a problem but `devtools::install()` errors out with the unhelpful output

> ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/R-3.3.0/library/gpuR'
>   * restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/R-3.3.0/library/gpuR'
>   Error: Command failed (1)

I cannot find any information online regarding what this exit error above could mean.  Any insights?

**Edit**

`devtools::build()` also fails with the following error:

> ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing 'C:/Users/...~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqG7nZV/Rinst84a432724f12/gpuR'
>         -----------------------------------
>   ERROR: package installation failed
>   Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Have you tried this: 
`devtools::document(".")` -> `devtools::build(".")` -> `devtools::install(".")`

Comment: @J_F The `build` call also fails as noted above.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Have you (in the case you use Windows) installed the newest RTools version?

Comment: @J_F I am in fact using Windows and I have installed the most recent Rtools (3.4)